# Zend Framework HTTP router

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a site with some static pages that lie in à folder called ../application/default/views/scripts/statiskt/student/(index.html) (seen from the webroot).

I can access these "static" pages via mydomain.se/statiskt/student/(index.html).

The problem is that i want to be able to access them via mydomain.se/student/(index.html).

I am using the Zend Framework with the Zend router.

I am barely familiar with the Zend Framework, so i'm asking you - Is this possible? And how do i achieve it?

Sent from an iPhone with weird spellchecking, sorry for any typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to modify any of the examples from the [ZF Manual on Routes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.static)?

```
  $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static(
      'student',
      array('controller' => 'statiskt', 
            'action' => 'student')
  );
  $router->addRoute('staticStudent', $route);
```

If there is no controller and action for the static pages, e.g. they are not used with ZF's MVC components, then rewrite the URL from the `.htaccess` in your `/pub` folder to point to the appropriate path. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html